# Asigning array for VBA doesn't work

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, arraylist

I wanted to find the mismatch of 2 different column in same sheet. I am using the dynamic array to store all the data of these 2 columns. But my code below having some error and I can't fix it.

```
Sub Mismatch()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim last As Integer
Dim BTID() As String
Dim CMF() As String

''find Mismatch
Sheets("Authorizations Issued").Select
Range("A1:BI1").Copy
Sheets("Mismatch").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Authorizations Issued").Select
last = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To last
    Range("A2").Select
    Sheets("Authorizations Issued").Select
    Do While Selection.Value <> "Cust Bill To ID"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop
    If Selection.Value = "Cust Bill To ID" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Select
        BTID(i) = Selection.Value
    End If
Next i

For j = 1 To last
    Range("A2").Select
    Do While Selection.Value <> "SAP CMF#"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop
    If Selection.Value = "SAP CMF#" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(j, 0).Select
        CMF(j) = Selection.Value
    End If
Next j

 Dim l As Integer
 l = 2

 For k = 3 To last
    If BTID(k) <> CMF(k) Then
       Range("$A$" & k & ":$BH$" & k).Copy

       Sheets("Mismatch").Select
       Range("$A$" & l).Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste
       l = l + 1

    Else: l = l

    End If
  Next k

 Sheets("Mismatch").Select
 ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
 Selection.EntireColumn.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

These two lines are highlighted.

```
BTID(i) = Selection.Value
CMF(j) = Selection.Value
```

Comment: You must declare the size of your arrays either when you dim them or, if you don't know in advance, in the code using `Redim`.

Comment: @SJR `Redim BTID(0)` added, but the result remain unchanged. :(

Comment: That will only hold one entry as arrays are zero-based (by default). You also really need to read up on how to avoid `Select`.

Comment: any better idea or example to make this code works? Please...

Comment: BTW, it works when I change the `BTID(i) = Selection.Value` to  `MsgBox Selection.Value`
Obviously the error is from the BTID() array.

Comment: You haven't said what error you are getting.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

use redim to dim your array

```
Sub Mismatch()


Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim last As Integer
Dim BTID() As String
Dim CMF() As String

''find Mismatch
Sheets("Authorizations Issued").Select
Range("A1:BI1").Copy
Sheets("Mismatch").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Authorizations Issued").Select
last = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count


For i = 1 To last
    Range("A2").Select
    Sheets("Authorizations Issued").Select
    Do While Selection.Value <> "Cust Bill To ID"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop
    If Selection.Value = "Cust Bill To ID" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Select
redim preserve BTID(i)
        BTID(i) = Selection.Value
    End If
Next i


For j = 1 To last
    Range("A2").Select
    Do While Selection.Value <> "SAP CMF#"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop
    If Selection.Value = "SAP CMF#" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(j, 0).Select
redim preserve CMF(J)
        CMF(j) = Selection.Value
    End If
Next j

 Dim l As Integer
 l = 2

 For k = 3 To last
    If BTID(k) <> CMF(k) Then
       Range("$A$" & k & ":$BH$" & k).Copy
       Sheets("Mismatch").Select
       Range("$A$" & l).Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste
       l = l + 1
    Else: l = l
    End If
  Next k
 Sheets("Mismatch").Select
 ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
 Selection.EntireColumn.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want, if I understand it as follows:

1. Copy the header row from Authorizations Sheet to the Mismatch sheet
2. Run through and compare the data between the "Cust Bill TO ID" and "SAP CMF#" columns of the Authorizaitions Sheet
3. Copy that rows data to the Mismatch Sheet

See code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Mismatch()


    Dim AuthIssuedsheet As Worksheet
    Set AuthIssuedsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Authorizations Issued")

    Dim MismatchSheet As Worksheet
    Set MismatchSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mismatch")

    'Copying the header of AuthIssuedsheet to MismatchSheet
    AuthIssuedsheet.Range("A1:BI1").Copy MismatchSheet.Range("A1")

    Dim AuthShtLastRow As Long

    'Finding last row of used data in Authorizations Issued sheet
    With AuthIssuedsheet
        AuthShtLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim AuthShtLastCol As Long

    'Finding last row of used data in Authorizations Issued sheet
    With AuthIssuedsheet
        AuthShtLastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With



    Dim CustBillCol As Range
    Dim SAPCMF As Range
    Dim CustBillArray As Variant
    Dim SAPCMFArray As Variant
    Dim CustBill_SAPCMF_Array As Variant

    With AuthIssuedsheet

    'Finds the header column with text Cust Bill To IF
    Set CustBillCol = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count)).Find( _
                What:="Cust Bill To ID", After:=AuthIssuedsheet.Range("A1"), _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    'Finds the header column with text SAP CMF#
    Set SAPCMF = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count)).Find( _
                What:="SAP CMF#", After:=AuthIssuedsheet.Range("A1"), _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    CustBillArray = .Range(.Cells(2, CustBillCol.Column), .Cells(AuthShtLastRow, CustBillCol.Column))
    SAPCMFArray = .Range(.Cells(2, SAPCMF.Column), .Cells(AuthShtLastRow, SAPCMF.Column))

    End With

    Dim ArrayPos As Long
    Dim LastRowMismatch As Long

    'deletes old data from Mismatch sheet before copying the mismatch data over
    MismatchSheet.Range(MismatchSheet.Rows(2), MismatchSheet.Rows(Rows.Count)).ClearContents

    'Looping through every value in the two arrays to check for mismatchs
    For ArrayPos = 1 To UBound(CustBillArray)

        If CustBillArray(ArrayPos, 1) <> SAPCMFArray(ArrayPos, 1) Then

            'Finding last row of used data in Mismatch sheet
            With MismatchSheet
                LastRowMismatch = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            End With
            'Copy the information acorss to mismatch sheet
                AuthIssuedsheet.Range(AuthIssuedsheet.Cells(ArrayPos + 1, 1), _
                                      AuthIssuedsheet.Cells(ArrayPos + 1, AuthShtLastCol)).Copy _
                    MismatchSheet.Range("" & "A" & LastRowMismatch + 1)

        End If


        'becasue you might be running through a large data set i just put a msgbox every 20% to
        'let user know it will be a while
        'Ideally you would have a Userform with progress for large data sets

        If ((ArrayPos / UBound(CustBillArray)) * 100) = 20 Or _
            ((ArrayPos / UBound(CustBillArray)) * 100) = 40 Or _
             ((ArrayPos / UBound(CustBillArray)) * 100) = 60 Or _
                ((ArrayPos / UBound(CustBillArray)) * 100) = 80 Then

            MsgBox "Currently on " & Fix((ArrayPos / UBound(CustBillArray)) * 100) & "%"

        End If



    Next ArrayPos

    MismatchSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    MsgBox "Complete!"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't make out what you try to do. This is as far as I got:-

```
Sub Mismatch()
    ' 07 Apr 2017

    Dim WsAut As Worksheet, WsMis As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long                                ' WsAut.LastRow
    Dim C As Long                                   ' WsAut.Column

    Set WsAut = Sheets("Authorizations Issued")
    Set WsMis = Sheets("Mismatch")

    With WsAut
        Last = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        .Range("A1:BI1").Copy Destination:=WsMis.Cells(1, 1)
'        consider this instead:-
'        Last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'find Mismatch
        For C = 2 To Last
            If .Cells(2, C).Value = "Cust Bill To ID" Then
    '            ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Select
                BTID(i) = Selection.Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

The first job is to get rid of all our Select commands. When using VBA, all your sheets are in memory and you access them by addressing them in the memory: Workbook.Worksheet.Cells (Row, Column). The Workbook is understood to be the active one. If you expect to run this code while another workbook is open you should add code to specify the workbook, perhaps the one containing the code.

Then I cam across the question why you specify the LastRow using the UsedRange. If you use the range A1:B10, that is the UsedRange. But if you now enter something in C24 and delete it again, the UsedRange will still be A1:C24. So, if possible, I suggest to define the last row as a non-blank cell in a column. But this requires that there should be no blank cells before the end of the column.

With the help of the new setup, your five rows of code copying range A1:BI2 could be compressed into a single line. But then I ran into trouble understanding what you want to do. It seems that you are looking for a column caption "Cust Bill To ID", but your use of Last indicates that you are looking at rows. Also, it looks like you intend to select the next cell when a match is found, but `ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Select` will select a cell i rows below the active cell, and that could be any number less than Last and specify a cell well below Last.

Accordingly, my loop `For C = 2 to Last` doesn't do anything useful. Perhaps you can describe your intention in plain words and then we can find code for it.

Comment: SOP:
1. Search from cell("A2"), to find the exact location of "Cust Bill To ID" and "CMF#"
2. Assign the two arrays with the data of these 2 columns.
3. Compare these 2 arrays, if mismatch copy entire row of data from Sheets("Authorizations Issued") to  Sheets("Mismatch"). @Variatus

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't tested the code, but the concept should be valid:

```
Sub Mismatch()

Dim authSht As Worksheet ' Renamed this variable
Dim misSht As Worksheet ' Added a worksheet variable
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim last As Integer
Dim BTID(1 To 1) As String ' We'll dim the arrays 1-based to avoid ninja arithmetics in the loop later
Dim CMF(1 To 1) As String
Dim rng1 As Range ' Added this variable
Dim rng2 As Range ' Added this variable

Set authSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Authorizations Issued")
Set misSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mismatch")

''find Mismatch
authSht.Range("A1:BI1").Copy
misSht.Range("A1").Paste

last = authSht.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Set rng1 = authSht.Range("A2")
Set rng2 = rng1

For Each c In Range(rng1, authSht.Range(rng1.Row, authSht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
    If c.Value = "Cust Bill To ID" Then Set rng1 = c
    If c.Value = "SAP CMF#" Then Set rng2 = c
Next c

For i = 1 To last
    BTID(i) = rng1.Offset(i, 0).Value
    CMF(i) = rng2.Offset(i, 0).Value

    If i < last Then ' If the loop will be executed at least 1 more time :
        ReDim Preserve BTID(1 To i + 1) ' .. resize the arrays to make room for the next entry
        ReDim Preserve CMF(1 To i + 1)
    End If
Next i


Dim l As Integer
l = 2

For k = 3 To last
    If BTID(k) <> CMF(k) Then
        authSht.Range("$A$" & k & ":$BH$" & k).Copy
        misSht.Range("$A$" & l).Paste
        l = l + 1
    Else
        l = l
    End If
Next k

misSht.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

In short:

- Using qualified ranges to get rid of all the various `Select` usage
- Pulled the two loops (`i` and `j`) into one, should save 20-40% macro runtime depending on dataset
- Array is now redimensioned

Further optimization:

- All the searching, adding, copying, etc. can be done in memory instead of on the sheet. For massive worksheets this will be a substantial improvement in speed. Especially the `k` loop - add to in-memory array instead, and when you're done push the array to the worksheet.
- Starting by defining your columns for "Cust Bill" and "SAP CMF" would eliminate the need for finding the correct ranges.